# Getting jquery and css transition effects working together

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have cloned this template :

```
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/
```

When you scroll-down, notice that the background-color of the header-link(About, Download, contact) on top will change to gray color (depending upon the section where you have scrolled).

I have made some small changes to the header wherien I am including font-awesome icons. The color effect has however stopped working.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-advance-options hide-this-nav">
<!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
    <li class="hidden">
        <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#flax">
            <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#moist">
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#designs">
            <i class="fa fa-paw"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0MV3QzRpJcPWlpuNMDav

Comment: What color effect has stopped working? The background color of the head links changes color for me. How does this relate to the font awesome icons?

Comment: The plnkr that I have created fails to do this

Comment: Okay I see. I was looking just at the demo site.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly where your javascript has gone wrong by the assets you've provided, but the issue is that on the font awesome icon version of the site (http://plnkr.co/edit/0MV3QzRpJcPWlpuNMDav), the `active` class is not being added to the menu `li` elements upon scroll, whereas it is being added to the `li` elements on the demo site (http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/).

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.. it didnt solve the issue but directed me in the right directionl

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by removing the following lines from second ul:

```
  <li class="hidden">
                <a href="#page-top"></a>
            </li>
```

I don't know why this solves the issue yet. If someone understands, kindly explain

Comment: Excellent - glad to hear James!